# Engine not found for the ".js" file extension

Tags: javascript, next.js, koa

I want to use [koa-views](https://github.com/queckezz/koa-views) with Koa and [Koa-Router](https://github.com/ZijianHe/koa-router) with Next.js. In previous projects, I had no issues with express but in this project, I have to use Koa. Using its router, I want to render a page: `/some/page/:id`. Following the same Nextjs way:

```
 router.get('/some/page/:id', async (ctx, next) => {
   const actualPage = '/some/page/id' // id.js (not actual name )
   await ctx.render(actualPage, {/* could pass object */})
 });
```

That would work if I was using express. With Koa:

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const views = require('koa-views');
// const render = require('koa-views-render'); <-- I what's this?

[..] // Making things short here
const server = new Koa();
const router = new Router();

// My issue, I'm seeing tutorials using other engines: .ejs etc
// I'm not using any, I only have .js files
server.use(views(__dirname + "/pages", { extension: 'js' }));
```

Using the same `router.get...` function as above, I get:

> Error: Engine not found for the ".js" file extension

When I go to `/some/page/123`, I'd expect it to render the file `/pages/some/page/id.js`. How?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I do not need any extra modules to achieve this

Create a function called, ie, routes then pass `app` and `router` as a param

```
const routes = (router, app) => {

  router.get('/some/page/:id', async (ctx) => {
    const { id } = ctx.params
    const actualPage = '/some/page/id'

    // Render the page
    await app.render(ctx.req, ctx.res, actualPage, {foo: 'Bar'})
  }

}

module.exports = routes
```

Inside your `server.js` file:

```
// const routes = require('./routes);
// const app = next({ dev }); // import other modules for this section
// app.prepare().then(() => {
//   const router = new Router();
//   [..]
//   routes(router, app)
// })
```

The commented out section is a slim down version to make a point in where things should be.